# Installing Pear PFM on OSX

Tags: php, macos, pear

I am trying to create a Pear package from my project on github that I have on my local repository, but I'm having alot of trouble getting pfm to work, here is the error I keep getting when I try to install:

```
Luciens-Macbook-Pro:quisbee-rails admin$ pear install PEAR_PackageFileManager_Cli
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/PEAR_PackageFileManager_Cli"
install failed
```

I am running on **PHP 5.5.15** and **pear 1.9.5**.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your pear config settings you'll probably see that the preferred state of packages to download is "stable"

```
$ pear config-show | grep preferred_state
```

Or, to be more efficient:

```
$ pear config-get preferred_state
```

So to download and install a package that is not marked stable, your best option is to include the version number when you attempt to install it:

```
$ sudo pear install PEAR_PackageFileManager_Cli-0.4.0
```

This should work ok for you - assuming you already have all dependencies installed. If not, this is easy to do with the following by including the --alldeps option:

```
$ sudo pear install --alldeps PEAR_PackageFileManager_Cli-0.4.0
```